# Esperanto discord server?

Tags: learning, speaking

I have a question concerning speaking practice, specifically, if there's any widely known **discord server** for *Esperantists* to discuss various topics and for beginners to practise speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [simple web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=discordo+servilo) brings up several that still seem to be active:

- [/r/Esperanto](https://discordapp.com/invite/TtY8gwK) (seems specifically for the community of [that sub-Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Esperanto/))
- [Esperanta Babilejo](https://discordapp.com/invite/a8rNExD) (found through [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Esperanto/comments/4zpu0c/introducing_the_resperanto_discord_server/d6xu49y/))
- [Linguisticae](https://discordapp.com/invite/haeyeXR) (also found through [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Esperanto/comments/4zpu0c/introducing_the_resperanto_discord_server/d6xu49y/))

Comment: I cannot recommend /r/Esperanto at Discord: very poor discussion both contentwise and languagewise,

Answer (score 1):

Linguisticae is a french linguistic youtubers who have a channel in esperanto